# jQuery Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this everything is just fine:

```
var hasPage = $(".my-class").children("a[href='/some/webpage/']").length;
if(hasPage < 1){
//do something 
}
```

But with this I get an unexpected identifier error on the hasPage variable.

```
var webPage = "'/some/webpage/'";
var hasPage = $(".my-class").children("a[href="webPage"]").length;
if(hasPage < 1){
//do something 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var webPage = "'/some/webpage/'";
$(".my-class").children("a[href=" + webPage + "]").length;
                                  ^         ^
```

Use your `webpage` var by concatenating properly.

Comment: var webPage still needed the "'  '" around it, but other than that it works now.